# Laravel doesn't updating data in db correctly

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Here is the code of function in my model:

```
public function updateAnime(Request $request)
{
    $updatedFields = [];

    $request->validate([
        'title' => ['required'],
        'release_date' => ['required', 'integer'],
        'author' => ['required'],
        'studio' => ['required'],
        'description' => ['required'],
    ]);

    $request->release_date = (int)$request->release_date;
    $animeInfo = Anime::where('title', $request->oldTitle)->with('authors', 'studios')->first();

    $author = Author::firstOrCreate(['author' => $request->author]);
    AuthorAnime::where([
        ['author', $animeInfo->authors[0]->author],
        ['anime', $request->oldTitle]
    ])->update([
        'author' => $author->author,
        'anime' => str_replace(' ', '-', $request->title)
    ]);

    $studio = Studio::firstOrCreate(['studio_name' => $request->studio]);
    StudioAnime::where([
        ['studio', $animeInfo->studios[0]->studio_name],
        ['anime', $request->oldTitle]
    ])->update([
        'studio' => $studio->studio_name,
        'anime' => str_replace(' ', '-', $request->title)
    ]);

    foreach ($request->all() as $key => $value) {
        if (property_exists($animeInfo, $key)) {
            if ($request->$key != $animeInfo->$key) {
                $updatedFields[$key] = $request->$key;
            }
        }
    }

    $animeInfo->update($updatedFields);
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Data was updated successfully. \n Updated data: ' . implode(', ', array_keys($updatedFields))]);
}
```

Code in controller:

```
        $anime = new Anime();
        return $anime->updateAnime($request);
```

The problem is that it updates related tables StudioAnime and AuthorAnime also it create new data in tables Studio and Anime but it doesn't update table Anime. Can somebody explain me why it happens and how to fix it please?

When in my previous code i just updated data without cheking it for changes all worked

````
        $animeInfo->update([
            'title' => str_replace(' ', '-',$request->title),
            'poster' => $animeInfo->poster,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'release_date' => $request->release_date,
            'trailer' => $animeInfo->trailer,
        ]);
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Data was updated successuflly']);```
````

Comment: Have you set *$fillable* porperty in Anime model?

Comment: Yes. $fillable = ['title', 'release_date', 'description', 'poster', 'trailer'];

Comment: Did you debug the *$updatedFields* variable after the `foreach ($request->all()...`?

Comment: Yes. It's empty array but i don't understand why. Perhaps the problem in foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the column names with the function *property_exist()* because the attibutes are not directely accessible as properties in the Model object.

To check this you can try in tinker:

```
dd(User::first())
```

I suggest you use the *attributesToArray()* or *getAttributes()* methods in conjunction with *array_keys()* to get an array of the model's attribute names:

```
$animeAttributes = array_keys($animeInfo->getAttributes());

foreach ($request->all() as $key => $value) {

    if (in_array($key, $animeAttributes)) {

    /* ... */
```

Comment: Thank you so mush! Now it all works